# pymongo ImportError: cannot import name _unicode

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

when i import pymongo in my virtualenv i get this error. The virtualenv is set up correctly.
Previously i used pymongo version 2.8 . I upgraded it to version 3.0.3 and after that i got this problem.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py in <module>()
     20 from bson.code import Code
     21 from bson.objectid import ObjectId
---> 22 from bson.py3compat import (_unicode,
     23                             integer_types,
     24                             string_type,

ImportError: cannot import name _unicode
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pip uninstall pymongo bson
pip install pymongo --upgrade
```

`_unicode` doesn't exist in the default `bson` package provided by `pymongo==2.8` (and neither does `integer_types`), so I'm not sure where you got that from.

I would recommend removing the pymongo and bson packages you have installed, and re-installing just pymongo and use the bson package it provides.

Answer (score 1):

On an ubuntu box (14.04):
sudo apt-get install python-pymongo
That version just works